# Laravel ORM relationship - manager-employee over the same table of users

Tags: laravel, orm

I have a `user_managers` pivot table that gets both keys from the users table:

- `employer_user_id`
- `employee_user_id`

I believe users would have a **many to many** relationship as a user can be managed by more than 1 manager there will be users who manage 1 or more users, while other users (excluding those under them) would manage them while there will be users who don't manage at all and a `User` can have only 1 manager.

My first try at defining this was to build another model named `Manager` representing the `user_managers` pivot table, so in `User` model I wrote the following 2 functions:

```
public function managedBy()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Manager', 'employer_user_id');
}

public function manages()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Manager', 'employee_user_id', 'employer_user_id');
}
```

Does this make sense or do you know of a better way to implement this kind of structure?

Comment: *A User can have only 1 manager* I don't see the need of many to many its more like one to many

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid - ok will fix, and do you agree with the functional representation above? especially with the 2nd `manages($id)` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If *a user can have only 1 manager* then you can define you relationship as one to many like

```
//User model 

public function managedBy()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'manager_id');
}

public function managees()
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'manager_id');
}
```

you don't need to pass `$id` to your relationship definition.

For multiple managers, Yes you would need a many to many relationship by adding a junction/pivot table which i guess you already have `user_managers`, Now you need to define your relationships using `belongsToMany` for managers and mangees like

```
public function managers()
{
    $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_managers', 'employer_user_id')
}

public function managees()
{
    $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_managers', 'employee_user_id')
}
```

Comment: I got updated now that a user can have many managers, even though it sounds arguably wrong in my eyes,  client says they have people who work in 2 departments that have diff. managers in each department. I will edit my question accordingly, so this means this would be Many To Many.

Comment: @clusterBuddy i have updated my answer for many to many relationship

Comment: so there is no need for a `Manager` model?

Comment: @clusterBuddy generally nope there is no need. But if you want to have any other relations for a pivot table then i guess you might need to define a model